# How to change/override all the y-values in a series to a single number in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot some data on a single line. Unfortunately, Trading View's hline() plotting function doesn't allow me to change it's color conditionally. The plot() function does, so I'm trying to use this one to plot my x-value data points onto.

I want to change/override all the y-values in a series to a single number.

Something like this

```
ema = ema(close, 100)
emaCustom = ema(close(close(x), 25), 200)// doesn't exist
```

Ideas? :)

Current dirty fix:

```
lineFixed = (close - close) + 25 // e.g. desired y-value 25 
// if I don't add at least one series to the formula, the plot() function won't work
lineColor = close > ema(close, 100) ? green : red
plot(linefixed, color=lineColor)
```

Comment: So you want to draw a horizontal line at a fixed y position, and change its color by looking at a condition? Am I right?

Comment: @BarisYakut Yes